# Print a desired string to console input

Tags: java, input, console, output

The main idea is: Some variable is printed to stdin, so the user can edit it and save, or keep unchanged. Like:

```
String value = "Old value";
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input new value or press \"Enter\" to keep an old value");
System.in.write(value);
value = scn.nextLine();
```

Comment: The question is "how do i write any text to a System.in stream, since it has no write or similar method".

Comment: you can't write to the stdin, that's the reason its called stdin and not stdout. can you specify why you want to do this?